# How to create custom popup menu with pointer in android

Tags: java, android, popup

I want to create a popup menu with a pointer to show which record is showing in the popup.

I've tried to custom Dialog from [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0DH2tZjJtm0) but it doesn't show a pointer.

What I want is something like the image below:

[image: Image example]

Comment: you just need the background image ith that *pointer*

Answer (score 0):

Use the background like this.

It should work

**Create a drawable.xml file "rectangle_shape.xml"**

```html
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="
        M2,2
        C2,2 2,1 3,1
        L 21,1
        C21,1 22,1 22,2
        L 22,21
        C22,21 22,22 21,22

        L 14,22
        L 12,24
        L 10,22

        C3,22 2,22 2,21 Z"
        android:strokeWidth="0.2"
        android:strokeColor="#dadada" />

</vector>
```

**Create a layout file like**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_shape">

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally inside **rlv1 relativelayout** page your code , and fix if any margin issue arise